# Changing Font Sizes In A Table Inside A Div

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
   <script>
if ((screen.width<=700) && (screen.height<=1200))
{
  document.getElementById("Table").style.fontSize = "64px";
}
else
{
  document.getElementById("Table").style.fontSize = "40px";
}
</script>
<body>
  <div id="Table">
  <center>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="60"         width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="center"><a href="https://www.google.com">Hello</a>    </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
  </div>
</body>`
```

I want to change the font size of everything inside the
   div
If that isn't possible then please tell me how to change the font size of only the tables.

Thanks

Comment: So what's wrong.  Does this not work? Do you get errors?

Comment: can use css media query to do this...no need for script

Comment: @cale_b it just remains the default font size.

Comment: @charlietfl please show me how...

Comment: google css media query. If setting table font size isn't working...you may have css rules for `td` or `tr` that have higher rank

Comment: I'm kind of new to css, used to using javascript and html.

Comment: <style>
  .Transition1
  {   
     color:#00adee;
     -webkit-transition:color .3s ease-in;
     text-decoration:none;
  }   
    a:hover{color:#ff5400;text-decoration:none;}
    </style>

Comment: would the above have a higher rank?

Comment: I don't know if this would affect it...

Comment: you can use css for change html styles...

    <style type="text/css">
    table
    {
    font-size: 50px;
    }
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

Move the `script` element to the end of the `body` element.

What happens now is (as you can see by looking at the console in Developer Tools of your browser, press F12 to enter them) is that `document.getElementById("Table")` yields `null`. The reason is that the browser executes the JavaScript code before it has parsed the HTML code that comes after the `script` element, so there is no element with `id` value of `Table`.

There are many ways to prevent JavaScript code from running before it can access all the data it needs. In this case, moving the `script` element is simplest.